# Bind d3 plot to shiny ui.R

Tags: javascript, html, r, d3.js, shiny

I am searching for a way to bind a `d3` plot to a `shiny` app.
The hintch is: The plot gets created dynamically on the `javascript` side. The trigger for the creation of the plot on the other side comes from the `shiny` app. [How it works.](https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/)

That means, something in the `ui.R` like `includeHTML("someJsWithPlot.js")` won't work (as described [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/d3-and-r-interacting-through-shiny/)), because the plot will be displayed upon user interaction, after the `index.html` is created.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355119/how-to-integrate-a-data-driven-d3js-graph-with-shin) on the ui.R side

```
tags$div(id = "#fromJs")
```

And this on the `.js` side

```
var w = 100;
var h = 100;
var test = d3.select("#fromJs").append("text")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

test.append("text")
 .text("Foobar")
 .attr("x",10)
 .attr("y",15);
```

That works! The text gets displayed in the `div` I created!
My idea was to replace the text with the plot. For a starter, I tried to replace it with a simple circle, but that does not work. Nothing gets displayed (nor an error thrown in the console).

```
var w = 100;
var h = 100;

var test = d3.select("#fromJs").append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

test.append("svg")
 .attr("x", 10)
 .attr("y", 15)
 .attr("r", 20);
```

I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29946252/can-i-use-index-html-and-ui-r-for-my-r-shiny-interface), but I do not find much on `shiny.OutputBinding()`, except [this](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-outputs.html) or [this](https://github.com/jcheng5/shiny-js-examples/tree/master/output). The latter one is not understandable to me.

Bottom line: How do I access a costum `div` from the `js` side? There seems to be a [workaround](https://github.com/SweetBabyJesus/shiny-d3js-simple-binding), but that looks like a hack... 
I am bit clueless where to start. Any hints?